# What format should the LSTM input have for the EEG classification?

Tags: classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to deep learning (and on this forum).

I have a problem understanding the input format of the LSTM network I try to build in a sequence classification problem. Here is my dataset:

```
       EEG_1     Labels_1      EEG_2    Labels_2 …

      epoch_1       1         epoch_1       1
      epoch_2       0         epoch_2       0
         …          …           …           …    
      epoch_n       1         epoch_n       1
```

Where each epoch contains 50 samples and where label is the class of those 50 samples.

For **one** EEG, the labels of the successive epochs are dependent, which is why I would like to develop an RNN allowing to learn how to classify each epoch of this signal. On the other hand, the different EEG are not linked together (it concerns different patients). So I would like the RNN to consider them as different examples in its learning process (The EEGs of two patients are independent)

While browsing through the literature, I have seen quite a few examples of how to feed **one** signal to an RNN. But never (or I misunderstood) several independent signals. Can you tell me how I can do that? The coin doesn't fall out. what would be the input format of this LSTM?

Thank you in advance